# Listening on running server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js

How to listen on server which is running on port `3000`? I want to show an notification when my server is switch off to the client but i don't know how to check if server is running. Can somebody tell me how to listen on server events?

I read about `socket.io`, it is a solution?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control of the server as in are you the one in control of the infrastructure the server is running on and responsible for turning it off and on again. If so separate socket based server can be setup that connects with client to let it know if the server is on or off. You can program a notification using this socket based server to let the client know.

If you dont have control of the server at all you can use polling on client side to know if the server is available. You can also just wrap all your client calls with prerequisite if the server is available and if the request times out then just set the notification accordingly.

Please note that without either having server send notifications via sockets there is no clean way for client to instantly know that server is down without very quick regular polling to the server which in turn may add a lot of extra load on the server.